# Simple XPath mapping and transformation (very basic)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Problem: I have Attributes in 2 different places. I want to use only 1 of these places in the output. So I have to map (?) corresponding Attribute/ID to the ElementAttributeID.

This is the XML I am trying to transform:

```
<ID>Testdata</ID>
<Attributes>
    <Attribute>
        <ID>Time</ID>
        <Name>Time</Name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <ID>Place</ID>
        <Name>Place</Name>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <ID>Sense</ID>
        <Name>Sense</Name>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Elements>
    <Element>
        <ID>First</ID>
        <Name>First</Name>
        <MGs>
            <MG>
                <Attributes>
                    <Attribute>
                        <ElementAttributeID>Time</ElementAttributeID>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <ElementAttributeID>Place</ElementAttributeID>
                    </Attribute>
                </Attributes>
            </MG>
        </MGs>
    </Element>
</Elements>
```

I have managed to write this cosmic piece of XSL

```
    <xsl:template match="MGs/MG/Attributes/Attribute">

    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <xsl:if test="./node() = parent::Attributes/Attribute">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(CubeAttributeID,' Matches ',parent::Attributes/Attribute) " /> From template
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

After the transformation i found that it has mapped only the found Attributes, BUT it will not map correctly as the output is:

```
Time Matches Time 
Place Matches Time
```

as the desired output would be:

```
Time Matches Time 
Place Matches Place
```

Do I need one nested for-each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit reading about how the testing in xsl works i got it right.
Didn't have to do mapping, only 1 variable which is used in foreach loop:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Elements/Element/MGs/MG/Attributes/Attribute">
          <xsl:variable name="id" select="ElementAttributeID" />
          <div>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(/Attributes/Attribute[ID=$id]/Name,'matches',/Elements/Element/MGs/MG/Attributes/Attribute/ElementAttributeID)"/>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives the correct result:

```
Time matches Time 
Place matches Place
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not right..

you are matching the template and then looping each match 1 at a time! remove the

```
<xsl:for-each select="." />
```

it essentially does nothing in this context as you are selecting the element which the template matches, so you are in simple terms looping your context node.

Also please update your question with your intended output and I am sure I can provide much more detailed help!

Additionally please ensure that your example xslt matches your example xml